# JPA abstract class share PK with subclasses

Tags: java, jpa

I was wondering if it is possible to have an abstract class and multiple subclasses that "share" the same PK (I want the ID to be unique between all subclasses of my abstract class):

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

@GeneratedValue(strategy=???) @Id
private long id;
...
}
```

and two subclasses

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity1 extends MyAbstractClass { ... }

@Entity
public class MyEntity2 extends MyAbstractClass { ... }
```

And the result that I want to achieve is that
MyEntity1's ID will never be the same with MyEntity2's ID.

Thanks for the time and opinions :)

LE: Found an answer, I've posted it bellow!

Comment: You can simply use the same sequence generator for all entities, if your database supports it. But why do you have this requirement?

Comment: @JBNizet : I have to persist two entities which are really similar with some small exceptions, and I do not want to put them in the same table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to obtain the desired result by using `TABLE` generation strategy

```
@TableGenerator(name = "myGen", table = "ID_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_KEY", valueColumnName = "GEN_VALUE", pkColumnValue = "NEXT_ID", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "myGen")
@Id
private long id;
```

The above code will generate a Table in the database which will act like a key-value pair. It will contain only one row in the form of `NEXT_ID --> (some number)`.

When inserting a new (subclass) in the database, it will use the (some number) id as the PK and the current number will be increased by 1.

This way, the subclasses ID's will never be the same across the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about your id's type, consider using a `UUID` key:

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@Id
private UUID id;
```

Then, no entity's ID will ever be the same with another entity's ID, no matter what.